# High Memory Usage in Flag series

Tags: javascript, memory, highcharts

Working with large data sets (50000+) for "flags" type of series I encountered huge memory usage leading to momentarily browser hanging and unresponsive webpage.

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50zab8tc/14/) there are 2 commented series, both with 10,000 values but one series type "line" and the other one type "flags", using Chrome's task manager you can see that the difference in memory usage between both is significant (10 MB vs 155 MB) (uncomment one series at a time, it can slow down your browser).

Here I leave the test code but with only 2 data values, the jsfiddle has 10,000.

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            series: [
///*            
            {type: 'line',
                name: 'Line on series',
                turboThreshold: 0,
                data:[[1465241389],[1465242389]]
            }
//*/
/*
            {type: 'flags',
                name: 'Flags on series',
                turboThreshold: 0,
                data: [{x:1465241389,title:''},{x:1465242389,title:''}],                
                onSeries: '',
                shape: 'squarepin'
            }
*/          
        ]});
    });
});
```

Looking at highstock src I noticed that in initSeries method a call to merge function is made. That function duplicates the series object including all it's DATA (10,000 values in the example), I don't know why it has to do this.

Is there a way to specify flags data with simple arrays? or a way to use over 50,000 flag values without the page hanging?

EDIT:

> Here's the example using type "line": http://jsfiddle.net/vzf3vr2p/1/
>   Here's the example using type "flags":http://jsfiddle.net/50zab8tc/15/

Comment: 1) Your example seems not work 2) Why you refer to empty string in onSeries param? Flags should be printed on xAxis or on series?

Comment: 1) In the example you need to uncomment the series you want to try out. I did that because it may hang your browser. 2) If you leave onSeries with an empty string flags are shown on the x Axis

Comment: Lets run two demos, first: http://jsfiddle.net/2jv54dfx/ and http://jsfiddle.net/2jv54dfx/. First demo, takes me 45mb of memory, second 61mb without increasing.

Comment: You pasted the same link in both cases, but you're right that is more clear like that. I updated the question with 2 jsfiddle links. With high data sets is where it's more evident

Comment: Sorry I mean second one: http://jsfiddle.net/5nr6xaz2/